# jquery modal popup box

Tags: jquery, css

I have an existing legacy web site, that customized the jquery css to a very detailed level, but now i want to implement a default skinned, jquery modal popup box on the form.

I did a quick test, and by doing to the default, simple modal popup dialog, but the settings from the highly customized css is stepping on the rendering of the popup modal dialog, rendering the popup unusable.

So my question is this....    is there a way to take the default modal popup css 'guts' from the standard jquery css files, and place them in a spot where they will not nessasarily override the entire page, but just be used in the section where the popup uses them?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: i have tried all kinds of stuff - with the latest being the !important stuff (thanks romi)

Answer (score 0):

Download the stylesheet file from jQuery website abd you could possibly idetify your main div or the element you put your jQuery popup in and make the jQuery styles only work for that section. I've seen the stylesheet file fr jQuery's modal popup and it seems to be quite a long process to add your dov class name before every style but I can suggest that from top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the `!important` marker in CSS. It is used when different style sheets manipulate the same style property on the same element. With it you can specify which style property receives the highest priority.

Have a look here, for more information on the topic:

http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Hope this helps. Have a great day.

Comment: Wow - that was some kind of website...  lots of information - thank you